# How do I get the ID of the response from Google Forms via a Google Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

How do I get responseId?

```
var form = FormApp.openById('myGoogleFormID');
var response = form.getResponse(responseId);

function onSubmit() {
  // Here I'd like to get the ID of the current response
}
```

I'd like to get the current ID of the response in order to manage a spreadsheet based on the values that were entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code.

### Code

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.response;
  var lastResponse = responses[responses.length - 1];

  Logger.log(lastResponse.getId());
}
```

I wasn't able to find a clear cut solution, thus ended up with this. It will simply get the `ID`of the last entry

Comment: I ended up using the same approach as you but my case is quite friendly because the number of responses are always the same; so I can count on some constants for the indexes. `itemResponses[INDEX_NUMBER].getResponse();`