# Can I access the response ID of a Google Forms response?

Tags: google-forms

Is there a way to get a response ID in the responses spreadsheet of a Google Forms?

I need it in order to keep track of responses that may have been edited as I match them with my own database of responses.  An edited response now looks just like a new response.  It has a different date/time and a different position in the spreadsheet.  I cannot match it by email address, because there may be multiple responses with the same email address.

If I disable edits, people who have the edit link can still edit their response.  Then Google Forms treats this as a new response, keeping both the old and the new response.

This answer seems to indicate that it is possible to get a response ID through Google Apps Script:  [Get the Id of the response from Google Forms via a Google Apps Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56757/get-the-id-of-the-response-from-google-forms-via-a-google-apps-script).

Is this the only way?

I don't know how to use Google Apps Script, so it would take me some time to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google Apps Script is the only way to get the response id.

Check out the forms and spreadsheets add-ons, maybe there's one that fit your needs.

Comment: Great.  After 3 hours I learned enough Google Apps Script to get the data I need, and I like it better than the default spreadsheet.